# Looping AsyncCallback and BeginReceive

Tags: c#, tcp, asynccallback

I want this line to be in a loop, it should receive the messages i sent from another client right away. ReceiveData function should always return the message to the client right away. But when i put this in an infinite loop, it gives connection errors. Although it gives errors, just like i wanted, the other client receives immediately. Can you guys help me about this? I am new at TCP/IP Socket Programming.

```
client.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
```

Comment: Consider posting more than 1 line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCP/IP Using BeginReceive in a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72439042/tcp-ip-using-beginreceive-in-a-loop). You just posted this, and while also not a very good question (not enough context) it at least had a little bit more context.